# Animate.css and DIVs off screen

Tags: jquery, html, aspect-ratio, hammer.js, animate.css

This is a bit of an odd question, but I've mocked up a picture to help explain...

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtUj6.jpg)

I envisage doing this with Animate.css (http://daneden.me/animate), and JQuery, and hammer.js for mobile devices.

Is this possible with those plugins?

I had a play with JQuery and could only get this working when the content DIVs were full width, not when part of the div was showing just off the screen.

The DIVs will also have their aspect ratios maintained, and the animated items within the DIVs will maintain their positions with absolute percentages.

I apologise if this is a bit convoluted! I suppose I should have posted these as seperate questions?

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: I don't have anything solid as of yet, I think I will ask seperate questions as this seems like a bit of a multi-issue. Thank you for responding!